# Exclude indirect class generation in TypeLite

Tags: typescript, typelite

If my class uses another class, TypeLite will generate a definition for that other class even if it is not marked with `TsClass` (or included via `.For`). 
If I have:

```
[TsClass]
public class Poco {
    public Guid Id { get; set;}
}
```

TypeLite will generate the following:

```
interface Poco {
    Id: Guid;
}
interface Guid {
}
```

I'd like to instruct TypeLite to omit the interface for Guid - I already have it defined elsewhere, and am using `<reference path=` to refer to it in that generated file. I was able to use the following trick to (conditionally) prevent TypeLite from generating module wrappers:

```
.WithModuleNameFormatter(( moduleName) => "")
```

I cannot find anything similar for classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TypeLite version >= 1.5.0**

Since the version 1.5.0 you can place the `[TsIgnore]` attribute on classes. Definitions for classes such aren't generated in the output file, but if a property references the ignored class, the type of the property is preserved.

---

**OLD ANSWER valid for versions < 1.5.0**

The underlaying TypeLite infrastructure supports this kind of behavior, but unfortunately it doesn't surface neither in the `[TsClass]` attribute nor in the fluent configuration classes. However you can use the `TsModelBuilder` class directly in the .tt file.

To make it work, you need to remove the `[TsClass]` attribute from your `Poco` class and add it to the model manually in the .tt file. Then add a custom `MemberTypeFormatter`, that overrides the output for properties of specific type.

```
<# 
    var ts = TypeScript
        .Definitions()
        .WithReference("Enums.ts")
        .ForLoadedAssemblies();
        .WithMemberTypeFormatter((TsProperty tsProperty, string memberTypeName) => {
            var externalDefinitions = new string[] { "Poco" };
            var propertyInfo = tsProperty.MemberInfo as System.Reflection.PropertyInfo;
            if (propertyInfo != null && externalDefinitions.Contains(propertyInfo.PropertyType.Name)) {
                return propertyInfo.PropertyType.Name;
            }

            var asCollection = tsProperty.PropertyType as TsCollection;
            var isCollection = asCollection != null;

            return memberTypeName + (isCollection ? string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("[]", asCollection.Dimension)) : "");
        });
    ts.ModelBuilder.Add<Poco>(false);
#>
```

Comment: This generates `Id: any;`, rather than preserving the type while omitting its definition (`Id: Guid`, with no `interface Guid`). Is there a way to simply suppress particular types, under the assumption that they will be, or are currently, manually defined?

Comment: I've updated the answer with additional information.

Comment: I've updates the answer with information about the latest verions of the library